# React-bootstrap - Handling multiple modals on same page

Tags: reactjs, react-bootstrap

I have a component with render method like this:

```
<ListGroup>
  {myarray.map(function(item, k) {
    return (
      <ListGroupItem
        key={item._id}
        bsStyle={item.status==='FAIL'?'danger':null}
        >
        Hello world
        &nbsp;
        <button onClick={showModal}>Open Modal</button> 
      </ListGroupItem>
    );
  })}
</ListGroup>
```

I would like to show the modal on clicking of button with text **Open Modal**. There will be many list items with the button, however the content of the modal will be different which is dynamic populated from `myArray`.

I'm stuck here, since `react-bootstrap` modal needs the `show` state which I'm not aware of how to handle from multiple modals on the same page.

Comment: You could abstract your `ListGroupItem` to its' own class which gives it its' own state. That would generate a modal for each item. If you only want one modal, perhaps you could pass the `k` variable to your `onClick` listener and then manage the output in the modal.